# VBA SQL Syntax Problems

Tags: sql, vba, syntax

I have the following SQL:

```
SQL = "UPDATE [TBLTMP] SET TBLTMP24 '" & Me.TOWN & "' WHERE TBLTMP00 = '" & "1" & "';"


Table name TBLTMP
Field to update TBLTMP24
Record to update TBLTMP00
```

I want to store the value of ‘Me.Town’ in the field TBLTMP24 which is in the table TBLTMP, record number 1, anyone have any ideas what might work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing an `=` in your SQL Statement after `TBLTMP24`. You're statement should be:

```
SQL = "UPDATE [TBLTMP] SET TBLTMP24 = '" & Me.TOWN & "' WHERE TBLTMP00 = '" & "1" & "';"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need is to add `=` into your query, like below:

```
SQL = "UPDATE TBLTMP SET TBLTMP24 = '" & Me.TOWN & "' WHERE TBLTMP00 = '" & "1" & "';"
```

If you want to change some columns add commas, like below:

```
SQL = "UPDATE TBLTMP SET TBLTMP24 = '" & Me.TOWN & "', another_col = '" & Me.another & "' WHERE TBLTMP00 = '" & "1" & "';"
```